# delete widget upon uninstall

Tags: widgets, uninstallation

I developped a plugin that makes use of the widgets. It is compatible with both pre-5.8 WordPress widgets (legacy widgets) and the new block editor widgets. The widgets of my plugin do nothing but adding shortcodes.

I was wondering if there is a way to delete widgets upon uninstall? I use an uninstall.php file to clean the user's WP, and would like to also remove the widgets upon uninstall. There is no valid reason for the user to keep them after uninstall.

I tried to find a way, but the only information I can find is about unregistering the widgets. Not about actually deleting them.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the widget registered as a `WP_Widget` or a block? Also, since this is not the default behaviour, this could have undesirable side effects for users. For example a user my remove the plugin for debugging purposes, and when they re-add it the widgets would be gone.

Comment: It can be register as booth (to take into account those who don't use the widget block editor, the legacy widget is available). Regarding the side-effect, I offer in the plugin the option to keep all settings; this would include the widgets as well.

Comment: You say it “can” be registered as both, but I’m asking how you’ve implemented it. Did you create a PHP WP_Widget class _and_ a JavaScript file for a block? It’s important to know because removing each kind will be an entirely different process.

Comment: Yes. It can be registered as block editor and pre-5.8 wordpress. I use both systems. I do have created a js block file should the user use block editor widget.

Comment: So, can you help me? I can't find any way to achieve that.